# Bluetooth pairing Galaxy Tab

Tags: bluetooth, script, bash, desktop

I would like connect my Galaxy TabS2 to my Raspberry Pi.
After that, I would like write a script to do it automatically.

[image: bluetoothctl]

When I do this with bluetoothctl, I have a message (Pairing Requested) at the end... and if I don't accept this message my device is not paired.

How I can skip this message?